# Delete column and next column based on text

Tags: r, dataframe, match, subset

I have a data like this :

[image]

and I want to delete the column which contain "rico" and also delete all next columns. I am looking to get this :
[image]

This is what i did but it doesnt work :

```
mydata = data.frame(
  X1 = c("john", "max", "jay", "douglas"),
  X2 = c("alexia", "miguel", "vince", "gary"),
  X3 = c("peter", "rico", "joe", "jenny"),
  X4 = c("marc", "kelly", "max", "jones")
)

mydata[,grepl("rico", names(mydata))]
```

Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset *mydata* with a range ending one before where `grepl` hits *rico*.

```
mydata[1:(grep("rico", mydata)-1)]
#mydata[1:(grep("rico", mydata)[1]-1)] #Alternative when there are more hists
#       X1     X2
#1    john alexia
#2     max miguel
#3     jay  vince
#4 douglas   gary
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Allways thought about this and tried to find a quasi `filter` fucntion for columns. Is there something like this out there?

Comment: @TarJae Maybe something like `mydata[cummax(grepl("rico", mydata)) == 0]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colSums` -

```
mydata[cumsum(colSums(mydata == 'rico') > 0) == 0]

#       X1     X2
#1    john alexia
#2     max miguel
#3     jay  vince
#4 douglas   gary
```

Using `colSums` we count number of times `'rico'` is present in each column, we create a logical vector by comparing it with  `> 0`, using `cumsum` we select all the columns before the 1st occurrence of the word.